# Trouble installing tabulizer package

Tags: r, installation, failed-installation, tabulizer

I used the following code to install the `tabulizer` package:

```
ghit::install_github(c("ropenscilabs/tabulizerjars", "ropenscilabs/tabulizer"), INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")
```

I get the following error when I run it:

```
ropenscilabs/tabulizerjars              ropenscilabs/tabulizer 

NA                                       NA 

Warning messages:

1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\library" C:\Users\borle\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQTDkF7/ghitdrat/src/contrib/tabulizerjars_0.1.2.tar.gz' had status 1 

2: In utils::install.packages(to_install, type = type, repos = repos,  :
  installation of package ‘tabulizerjars’ had non-zero exit status

3: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\library" C:\Users\borle\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQTDkF7/ghitdrat/src/contrib/tabulizer_0.1.22.tar.gz' had status 1 

4: In utils::install.packages(to_install, type = type, repos = repos,  :
  installation of package ‘tabulizer’ had non-zero exit status
```

What has gone wrong here? What do the 'Warning messages' mean?

I am using 64-bit R 3.2.3 version and jdk1.7.0_79. My JAVA_HOME is set correctly to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre".

I had `tabulizer` installed previously and my code ran fine. Got an output too converting from PDF. But then I ran into jvm.dll file missing issue, so I uninstalled then reinstalled all packages (`rJava`, `miniUI`, `shiny` and `tabulizer`) as well as the jdk.

Can someone please help me understand how do I troubleshoot this and successfully install the `tabulizer` package in R?

Answer (score 9):

So, I found an answer on github. Didn't come up in my google search earlier.
Original installation code which didn't work -

```
remotes::install_github(c("ropenscilabs/tabulizerjars", "ropenscilabs/tabulizer"), INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")
```

Link to the issue and answers is here https://github.com/ropenscilabs/tabulizer/issues/14

The below code worked for me. Now, I have the following versions installed -

leeper/tabulizerjars:   "0.1.2"
leeper/tabulizer: "0.1.22"

```
remotes::install_github(c("remotes/tabulizerjars", "remotes/tabulizer"), INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch", dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports"))
```

Comment: first install 'ghit'  with 'install.packages("ghit")'  then run 'library(ghit)'and then the code above

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ropensci/tabulizer",  dependencies = "FALSE")
```

you want to install the other packages that tabulizer uses one by one as well i.e. rJava, httpuv, sourcetools, png

Answer (score 0):

`install.packages("remotes")` # get Package if you don’t have it

```
library(remotes)

remotes::install_github(c("ropensci/tabulizerjars", "ropensci/tabulizer"), INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch", dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports"))
```

If this results in errors install the packages one bay one

`install.packages("dplyr")` # get Package if you don’t have it

```
library(dplyr)

packs <- c('stringi', 'httpuv', 'digest', 'htmltools', 'sourcetools', 'evaluate', 'markdown', 
           'stringr', 'yaml', 'rJava', 'testthat')

laply(packs, function(x){
  install.packages(x)  
  readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue")
}
  )
```

If there are errors post them on Stack. If none of the packs gives an error (therefore the Press [enter] to continue), you can install tabulizer with

```
remotes::install_github(c("ropensci/tabulizerjars", "ropensci/tabulizer"), INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch", dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports"))
```