# Error in installing Tabulizer

Tags: r, github, installation, tabulizer

Using the instructions described in [github](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer#installation) and installing Java accordingly with Chocolatey -- plus installing `rJava` and setting the path in R with `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131")`-- I've done the following in R:

```
library(ghit)
library(git2r)
ghit::install_github(c("leeper/tabulizerjars", "leeper/tabulizer"), INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch", dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports"))
```

Which is the solution provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132202/trouble-installing-tabulizer-package). I get the following error:

```
Error in git2r::init(d) : 
  Error in 'git2r_repository_init': Unable to init repository
```

Setting the option `VERBOSE = TRUE` in `install_github` I get the following additional output:

```
Parsing reponame for 'leeper/tabulizerjars'...
Creating local git repository for tabulizerjars in C:\Users\JOOCAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgnitDP\tabulizerjars1643e0126f5...
Error in git2r::init(d) : 
  Error in 'git2r_repository_init': Unable to init repository
```

I read this [answer](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer/issues/54) and it seems that it has to do with my username, which is spaced and has accents. But how do I configure this?

---

edit: 6/4/2017 1:57 am

Following user @jaySf answer, I run part of the code of his answer (since I've already installed `rJava` and `devtools`):

```
library(rJava) # load and attach 'rJava' now
devtools::install_github("ropensci/tabulizer", args="--no-multiarch")
```

And got the following error:

```
> library(rJava) # load and attach 'rJava' now
> devtools::install_github("ropensci/tabulizer", args="--no-multiarch")
Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/tabulizer@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/ropensci/tabulizer/zipball/master
Installing tabulizer
Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/tabulizerjars@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/ropensci/tabulizerjars/zipball/master
Installing tabulizerjars
"C:/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL "C:/Users/Joo  \
  Caos/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpgh9eJi/devtoolsb3c50925145/ropensci-tabulizerjars-c6cc40e" --library="C:/R-3.4.0/library" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'tabulizerjars' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tabulizerjars':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/R-3.4.0/library/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/R-3.4.0/library/tabulizerjars'
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
"C:/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL "C:/Users/Joo  \
  Caos/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpgh9eJi/devtoolsb3c4a2835ec/ropensci-tabulizer-a38d957" --library="C:/R-3.4.0/library" --install-tests --no-multiarch 

ERROR: dependency 'tabulizerjars' is not available for package 'tabulizer'
* removing 'C:/R-3.4.0/library/tabulizer'
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

I believe that I might have a problem with my username in the file directory path, but I'm not sure. I tried using `install_github` with `ggplot2` --`install_github("wch/ggplot2") -- and it worked fine. If my guess is correct, how can I edit the file path?

---

**Problem solved**

I was running R with both 32 bit and 64 bit files installed. I cannot clearly state what were the problems in doing this, since as I ran `Sys.getenv("R_ARCH")` it returned `x64` previously, but when I uninstalled the 32 bit files, it ran perfectly well with @jaySf code.

Comment: Plus, I've installed `rJava` too

Comment: Just edit all relevant information into your question.

Comment: I`ve done it now.

Comment: The answers here all appear outdated, or at least do not work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps in given order should work:

```
install.packages("rJava")
library(rJava) # load and attach 'rJava' now
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("ropensci/tabulizer", args="--no-multiarch")
```

I'm using R 3.4.0 on win64, and described the procedure in a [former answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141160/recognize-pdf-table-using-r/44147228#44147228).

Comment: See my updated answer. I'm doing all this from RStudio, if that is relevant. I ran your code and still I cannot install `tabulizer`.

Comment: Me too, RStudio 1.0.143. Have you tried deinstalling rJava, devtools first? I can remember it was quite tricky to bring `tabulizer` onto my machine.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running x64? Your error message says: "ERROR: loading failed for 'i386' ". One more slight difference: I have installed the Java _JRE_ only, `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131`, but should be included in the _JDK_.

Comment: I think you grasped what I needed to do! I've ran `Sys.getenv("R_ARCH")`which returned `x64`. But then I uninstalled both R and Rstudio and reinstalled then, but I've installed only the 64 bit files this time as a test. And it worked! I think RStudio was searching through 32bit files in R.

Comment: Since this solution was clearly somehow pointed out by you, I'm awarding you with the answer o/

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

```r
devtools::install_github("ropensci/tabulizerjars", INSTALL_opts = c("--no-multiarch")) 

devtools::install_github("ropensci/tabulizer", INSTALL_opts = c("--no-multiarch"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("rJava")
library(rJava) # load and attach 'rJava' now
install.packages("devtools")
#run below package first..
devtools::install_github("ropensci/tabulizerjars", args="--no-multiarch") 
devtools::install_github("ropensci/tabulizer", args="--no-multiarch")
```