# Error in importing the package "tabulizer"

Tags: r, rjava, install.packages, tabulizer

when I import the package "tabulizer" I get this error (see the picture), can anyone help with this, plese?

[image: Tabulizer error]

Comment: Based on error: we need rJava and tabulizerjars installed.

Comment: See if this post helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37735108/680068

Comment: Please paste your error messages as text, images are unsearchable.

Comment: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tabulizer’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tabulizerjars', details:
  call: NULL
  error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tabulizer’ was built under R version 3.6.3

Comment: I'm checking the post you attached the link of but since I'm using the computer of my company I don't have authority in managing software installations.

Comment: Then you will need IT Support to install the tabulizer package, as it depends on rJava.

Comment: so I can't install another version of Java. Thank you for your help anyway

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in installing Tabulizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346656/error-in-installing-tabulizer)